# Hibernate: Discriminator based multi tenancy using filter?

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant, hibernate-filters

I have read several articles (i.e. [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Multi-tenancyDesign) and [that](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/47817/0/page/2) and [that](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html)) on the web regarding multi tenancy (for different clients in a SaaS application). Once you have decided to go for the discriminator based approach, the [hibernate doc states](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html), that this is not supported in version 4, but will come in version 5.

Nevertheless, you may find several articles about using hibernate filters for that purpose (i.e. [this](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/47817/0/page/2) and [that](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Multi-tenancyDesign)).

I am wondering, why there will be some special implementation for it in version 5, if a filter based solution would be fine. Thus: What are the drawbacks of the filter based solution? (I have [read](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6054) (see comment from 06/Dec/11) that they do not work with find statements. But no other souce seems to approve that. Is this true?)

Comment: have you tried it in a minimal example?

Answer (score 3):

Some drawbacks of filter based solution:

- When persisting, one must take care of tenant_id, it is not persisted automatically. Probably one could use a @PrePersist callback method.
- Method entityManager.find(EntityClass.class, "ID") doesn't take filter value into account
- Have to take care of @OneToMany relations like this:

```java
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
     @Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantId")
     private List<ArticleChild> children;
```

Comment: Hey, is this an exhaustive list of the cases that are missed by the filter ?

Comment: I'm considering to go with Eclipselink because of this drawbacks